# In Tridion UI-2012, the position of the selection area of CPs is not in the proper place

Tags: experience-manager

In Tridion UI-2012, the position of the selection area around the Component Presentations is not in the proper place. Instead of coming around the CPs as a wrapper, it shows below the CP.

This issue is mainly with chrome while in IE it is working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, perhaps you can supply a link to a screenshot and add the HTML of the page and elaborate a bit more on the problem you are having and want help with?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're seeing? It also would be quite helpful if you can share **the relevant parts** of your HTML.

Comment: The rendered HTML will help along with the code (e.g. DWT) that creates it and any template settings (Enable inline editing TBB parameter settings). Common implementation issues with borders are things like invalid markup or choosing the wrong wrapping element, but we're only guessing without seeing the setup.

Comment: I have to agree with Bart, Frank and Alvin that more detailed information about your problem is required to provide you with any sort of specific answer to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this behavior before in Chrome and Firefox when my component presentations do not have a container html element as the parent html element like a Div, can you please share the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

one of the issue could be due to missing Parent div as mentioned by Eric, other could be if enclosing div or child div has "Float left" properties set.